# two parameters in one url

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, parameter-passing

Can I have two params in one url such as:

```
localhost/post/image/id/something/else/value
```

where id is a param and something is the value and where else is the param and value is the value.

In zend I can only get the first param via:
    $this->_getParam('id');

This method doesn't work for the second parameter.

Any ideas?

Comment: It should work normally. Do you get any errors when you want to get the second parameter?Maybe you have some custom routes that conflict with something?

Answer (score 0):

use ? to separate the variables in the querystring

something like `http://localhost/post.php?imgID=1&otherValue=othervalue`

Comment: ? ofr the ifrst and & for the rest

Comment: How does this work in Zend? That doesn't really fall inline with using MVC style urls does it?.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working fine. Make sure you application.ini and plugins are doing default routing.

Default Zend Route looks like this:

With Out module

domainName/controller/action/var1/value1/var2/value2

With module

domainName/module/controller/action/var1/value1/var2/value2

Check following link for default Zend routes:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.default-routes